# Inspiration Request: Retro, fashion, funky, artist, punk

Tags: website-design, resource-recommendations

First time poster, long time viewer...As the title suggested, I'm looking for some inspirational websites/designs that have a funky retro look, but with mix of artistry and fashion to them.  It's quite a range, but I wanted to see if anyone out there has any links.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

there is only one website that Truly fits "Retro, fashion, funky, artist, punk" and that is [www.iso50.com](http://iso50.com/iso50.html)

Hope you like it :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely certain if these may inspire you, but:

http://sitesquared.com/

http://www.ochumarequartet.com/ochumare-quartet/?lang=en

As for a standard "punk" design: http://www.bluebanana.com/

Answer (score 0):

For general design inspiration try: http://www.cssdrive.com/ and http://thedesigninspiration.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try http://Kontrib.it its a new concept and a very new site, but pretty good inspiration collections are available right now.. Not directly website visuals but any visual, sound or video.. pretty much fits your needs.

Also http://designspiration.net/ is fine..